# How does this forward regex example work?

Tags: regex

If forward references are supported, the regex **(\2two|(one))+** matches oneonetwo.

> At the start of the string, \2 fails. Trying the other alternative,

So the fact that the "/2" fails means that the following "two" is skipped?

> one is matched by the second capturing group, and subsequently by the first group.

I understand the "second capturing group" but how does it get matched by the "first group"? And also if it gets matched two times why do we get "oneonetwo" instead of "oneoneonetwo" in the final result?

> The first group is then repeated. This time, \2 matches one as captured by the second group. two then matches two. With two repetitions of the first group, the regex has matched the whole subject string.

The example is taken from here:

https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html

Comment: This strikes me as being more of a brainteaser than an actual regex you would ever find yourself using.  But in any case, best way to understand it is to play around using a tool like www.regex101.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(\2two|(one))+` corresponds to the following instructions:

```
(    # start recording (for capture buffer 1)
    \2   # match the string that is stored in capture buffer 2
    two  # match "two" literally
  |    # or
    (    # start recording (for capture buffer 2)
    one  # match "one" literally
    )    # stop recording; set capture buffer 2
)    # stop recording; set capture buffer 1
+    # repeat the previous thing 1 or more times
```

Let's say the target string is `oneonetwo`. What happens next?

We start at offset 0 in the target string and the beginning of the regex.

Logically the first thing to be executed is `+`; it's the top level operation in the regex. It tries to match its sub-regex repeatedly (1 or more times).

`(` starts recording for capture buffer 1, but doesn't really do anything otherwise.

`\2` tries to match the string from capture buffer 2, but capture buffer 2 is unset. This behaves like a string that never matches, so the whole first alternative fails to match.

`|` kicks in and we try the second alternative.

`(` starts recording for capture buffer 2.

We try to match `one` and succeed: There's a `one` at offset 0 in the target string. We increment our position in the string (remaining characters: `onetwo`) and continue matching.

`)` stops recording; capture buffer 2 is now set to `one`.

`)` stops recording; capture buffer 1 is now set to `one`.

Our first iteration of the loop was successful. We try to match more (because that's what `+` does):

`(` starts recording for capture buffer 1 (again).

`\2` tries to match the string from capture buffer 2, which is now `one`. This succeeds because there's a `one` at the current offset in the target string. We increment our position in the string (remaining characters: `two`) and continue matching.

We try to match `two` and succeed. Our position in the target string is now at the very end.

`|` sees that the first alternative succeeded; we ignore the other alternative for now.

`)` stops recording; capture buffer 1 is now set to `onetwo`.

This concludes the second iteration of the loop. Again we try to match more:

`(` starts recording for capture buffer 1.

`\2` tries to match the string from capture buffer 2, which is still `one`. This fails (there are no characters left in the target string).

`|` kicks in and we try the second alternative.

`(` starts recording for capture buffer 2.

We try to match `one` and fail again (there are no characters left in the target string).

The second alternative fails to match, so the whole subgroup fails (and we throw away the last recording we started for capture buffer 2).

Control returns to `+`. We have matched two full iterations of the loop (the third one failed). This is fine (two is a perfectly fine instance of "1 or more").

We go on, reaching the end of the regex. This means the whole regex matched successfully. In the end, capture buffer 1 contains `onetwo` and capture buffer 2 contains `one`.

Specifically:

```
oneonetwo
^^^ #1
^^^ #2
```

^ After the first iteration.

```
oneonetwo
   ^^^^^^ #1
^^^ #2
```

^ After the second iteration.

Comment: Does the capture group buffer carry from one match to the next?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Depends on what you mean by "match". :-) A capture buffer doesn't persist from one regex match to the next (if your program uses multiple regexes), but it remains set within a single regex until it is overwritten by another execution of its capture group or until the execution that set it is backtracked out of. It behaves like a sort of dynamically scoped variable that's global to its whole pattern.

Comment: Rats...I see it now.  The entire pattern is quantified with `+`.  So that first `one` sits in `\2` to be used with `onetwo` +1.